# Why is Action<"test", boolean> spread into union of Action<"test", true> | Action<"test", false>

Tags: typescript

The definition of Action is

```
    type Action<T = string, P = any> = { p: P }["p"] extends undefined
        ? { type: T; payload?: P }
        : { type: T; payload: P };
```

But even though I have wrapped the checking of payload in object, it is still getting spreaded into union:

```
type Actions =  Action<"runTest", boolean>
```

resolves to

[image]

I don't want it to get spreaded. How do I keep the type of payload to be boolean?

Comment: Aren't they equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `{ p: P }["p"]` resolves `P` which is a naked type parameter. Conditional types distribute over naked type parameters, as you can read about in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

You can disable distribution by wrapping the type parameter in a tuple type:

```
type Action<T = string, P = any> = [P] extends [undefined]
        ? { type: T; payload?: P }
        : { type: T; payload: P };


type Actions =  Action<"runTest", boolean>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYB4AqUC8UDOwAToqgOYA0UACrlAIaogB8dA2tQLpQQAewEVABN8UNgFdhEAGakIQzgFgAUFDXq1AfigBvKKEgAuKJgDcUMPRAAbZPSGbjtAL4qNG43oMRjZi1dt7JyhnUxVw5W9YBBRUUTxopDR0ACIiSUwIQhSqACNkZGsIRmYgA)

Comment: Note that it's not necessarily obvious why `{p: P}["p"]` is a naked type parameter for the purpose of distributive types, since it depends on *when* that gets resolved.  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43727 is relevant